# Use symbol in URL using Flask

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to create a web app like a social network. Ideally, the URL to a user's page would look like:

> http://my-web-app.com/@user

I would like to use a symbol after the domain, the at (@) symbol in this case. Is it possible to do this using Flask?

I am aware of using URL parameters and Flask's Blueprints, but I prefer this notation more.

Thank you.

Comment: You will have to encode the `@` as `%40`. An `@` in the URL makes everyting before it (and after the schema) a username. As in `http://username:password@www.example.com`. Also security system can considered it dangerous since this has been abused for scam like in `http://www.your_bank.com/login@some.strange.hostname.biz/index.html`.